# Node JS Mailin SMTP Authentication credentials

Tags: node.js, email, smtp

I try to develop my SMTP server, and for this task I use Mailin module - 
[Mailin on GitHub](https://github.com/Flolagale/mailin)

but my Mailin SMTP server return 535 error (Authentication credentials invalid), when I try to auth user.

My start function with options:

```
mailin.start({
    port: 2525,
    disableWebhook: true,
    smtpOptions: {
        banner: 'Hello Smtp Server',
        logger: true,
        requireAuthentication: true,
        authMethods: ['PLAIN', 'LOGIN'],
        disabledCommands: ['STARTTLS'],
        ignoreTLS: true,
    }
})
```

and my user auth event listener:

```
mailin.on('authorizeUser', function(connection, username, password, done) {
    console.log(username, password);
    done(null, true);
});
```

and this is server logs:

```
info: Mailin Smtp server listening on port 2525
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] INFO: [Yl+t89fMiD31] Connection from [127.0.0.1]
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] S: 220 MacBook-Air-Egor.local ESMTP ePost Smtp Server
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] C: ehlo MacBook-Air-Egor.local
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] S: 250-MacBook-Air-Egor.local Nice to meet you, [127.0.0.1]
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SMTPUTF8
250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] C: AUTH LOGIN
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] S: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] C: YWJj
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] S: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] C: ZGVm
abc def
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] INFO: [Yl+t89fMiD31] Authentication failed for abc using LOGIN
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] S: 535 Error: Authentication credentials invalid
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] INFO: [Yl+t89fMiD31] Authentication error for abc using LOGIN
Unauthorized user
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] S: 535 Unauthorized user
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] C: 
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] DEBUG: [Yl+t89fMiD31] S: 500 Error: command not recognized
[2016-08-01 20:32:52] INFO: [Yl+t89fMiD31] Connection closed to [127.0.0.1]
```

So, what I do wrong, and why I get this error ?

Comment: Your error explain itself. "Authentication failed for abc". Re-check your credentials and make sure that you have all access right to connect .Hope this helps.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk, can you say me, where is this credentials configure ?

Comment: I pretty sure that this lib have some requirements. Read docs carefully and find out all dependencies that they require.  http://mailin.io/doc . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know that in the documentation it says to respond with

```
done(null, { user: 123} ); // where 123 is the User id
```

[smpt-server docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smtp-server#password-based-authentication) :: in the docs `callback` is equivalent to above `done`

disclaimer... I found this answer in my attempts to get this working so I am not an expert :)

Comment: I confirmed this after thoroughly going through the source codes for an npm package "smtp-server". Check https://github.com/nodemailer/smtp-server/blob/v1.4.0/lib/sasl.js on line 100 for reference.